# Subtracting hours and minutes

Tags: linux, perl

I would like to subtract 17 hours and 5 minutes from 10 hours and 0 minutes.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use Time::Piece;

my $t1 = Time::Piece->strptime( '10:00', '%H:%M' );
my $t2 = Time::Piece->strptime( '17:05', '%H:%M' );

my $t = $t2 - $t1;
print $t->hour;
print $t->min;
```

but I get the error

```
Can't locate object method "hour" via package "Time::Seconds"
```

I don't have a preference for [Time::Piece](http://perldoc.perl.org/Time/Piece.html). It just seamed popular and already installed on Linux.

**Question**

Can anyone see why this fails?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the documentation points out, a difference between two Time::Piece objects is a Time::Seconds object. So you need to use that as well and use the corresponding methods.

```
use Time::Piece;
use Time::Seconds;    # Already included in Time::Piece

my $t1 = Time::Piece->strptime( '10:00', '%H:%M' );
my $t2 = Time::Piece->strptime( '17:05', '%H:%M' );

my $t = $t2 - $t1;    # $t is now a Time::Seconds object
print $t->hours;      # The method of which is called hours instead of hour.
print $t->minutes;
```

The output will likely not be what you hope for as it gives decimal values. However, as Zaid points out:

```
print $t->pretty;
```

takes care of that.

Comment: Or simply `print $t->pretty;` gives `7 hours, 5 minutes, 0 seconds`

Comment: Why are `Time::Seconds` needed? The perldoc for `Time::Piece` have `$t->hour` listed. Yes, I would prefer to have 7 hours and 5 minutes returned =)

Comment: @JasmineLognnes : `Time::Seconds` does not need to be explicitly `use`-d as it is internally called by `Time::Piece`

Comment: The issue is that `Time::Piece` objects in fact represent dates. Subtracting one date from another does not result in another date but in a time difference represented by a `Time::Seconds` object. So the problem is not that there is no `->hour` in `Time::Piece` but that `$t` is no `Time::Piece` object and thus you have to use the `Time::Seconds` objects method which is called `hours` instead of `hour`.